# Wysiwyg for Drupal 7

Tags: wysiwyg, drupal

Скажите, что лучше использовать в качестве визуального редактора Ckeditor или TinyMCE? Какие преимущества? Особенности в настройках и сложность.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы вам посоветовал TinyMCE. Он более известен, есть официальный русский клуб. TinyMCE также более гибок, легко "принимает" плагины и дополнения (которые и писать легко). Если возникнут какие-либо вопросы, то на [drupal.ru](http://www.drupal.ru/forum) вам помогут (если её нет в уже решенных).

Я немного времени потратил на вставку TinyMCE в админку на php, написанную  с нуля, а уж вставить в CMS - ну вы поняли.